# Handling questions about Jenkins/CI

Tags: discussion

It seems like many of the questions tagged [Jenkins](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jenkins) (or git for that matter, but that might be a separate question) that come through really aren't about testing, but "how do I solve this problem in Jenkins [that I'm having with configuring something that happens to be related to testing]".

As I explained to the OP on [one question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30269/jenkins-warnings-plugin-excluding-messages), "The fact that the content of what you're trying to [do in Jenkins] happens to be about testing doesn't mean the technical issue itself is specific to testing."

Should such questions be on-topic here? Could we more clearly define what a good on-topic CI question is and update tag descriptions (at least the Jenkins tag, there may be more)?

In general I think such questions will get better answers on SO or devops.

Comment: The new question https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30776/generation-of-allure-report-through-jenkins is what prompted me to ask this. Granted, I'm not familiar with this particular plugin, but nothing about the question says "testing", at least to me.

Comment: That specific plugin is for a QA tool, but it still counts as off-topic in my opinion because there isn't enough information in the question to even think of answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several interrelated issues here.

1. People who ask questions but don't provide enough information for an answer. This seems to be a chronic problem - I've lost count of how many times I've pointed people to the help topic on how to ask a good question, and can count on one hand the number of times I've seen a poorly written question edited into something better.
2. People assuming that because something is a testing tool questions about configuration or support of that tool are on topic here. If the problem is a programming problem it should be asked in Stack Overflow (although most of the programming questions I've seen here would be downvoted to oblivion in seconds over there because they're too simplistic). If it's a configuration issue, the tool support forum is a better choice. And so on.
3. Inadequate tag wikis - I've been working on this when I have time and explicitly including usage guidance, going from the most used tags down as well as nixing edits that don't provide any usage guidance, but that doesn't mean people are paying attention to them.
4. Defining good on-topic questions about *x* - This should, I think, go into the tag wiki although I'm open to other thoughts and the option of adding to the help pages instead.

I think in flagging the questions that involve some testing tool but aren't actually *about* testing you're doing the right thing. I'll try to keep the wiki tag edit updates going and see if it's feasible to add sub-pages to the help section on some of the most abused tags.